# Setting Logging Levels for nested classes in Spring Boot Properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

I am attempting to set logging levels separately for 2 nested class loggers, an example of this being loggers that are named:

`com.package.ParentClass$LoggerOne` and `com.package.ParentClass$LoggerTwo`.  Adding loggers in the logback.xml file for those exact loggers works fine, but it doesn't seem to have any effect when trying to set the loggers for spring boot's `logging.level` properties group.

A class with these loggers would look something like this:

```java
class ParentClass {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ParentClass.class);

    // code that uses ParentClass logger

    class LoggerOne {

        private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerOne.class);

        // code that uses LoggerOne logger


    }

    class LoggerTwo {

        private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerTwo.class);

        // code that uses LoggerTwo logger

    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution, [as found on this GitHub issues comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/714#issuecomment-399489205), is to surround the logger class / sub-class in `[]`.

Example:

```
logging:
  level:
    com.package.[ParentClass$LoggerOne]: INFO
    com.package.[ParentClass$LoggerTwo]: ERROR
    com.package.ParentClass: DEBUG
```

This allows fine-grained control of logging levels for the parent class and any nested class contained within the parent.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use brackets, and it works for me:

```
logging.level.com.package[ParentClass$LoggerOne]=INFO
logging.level.com.package[ParentClass$LoggerTwo]=DEBUG
```